# What types of objects are found in relational databases?

Tags: mysql, sql, object, relational

What is the answer to this question? I'm searching but all I find is about object-relational databases which may not be the answer.

Comment: [This is a list of the types of objects that are found in a typical relational database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-types.html).... in this case, MySQL

Comment: But what do you mean by an "object relational database"? An ORD isn't the same as a relational database

Comment: Are you confusing issues between a "relational database" (like MySQL or PostgreSQL), and an "object relational mapper" (like Doctrine, Propel or Eloquent)?

Comment: Yeah, the question is goofy.  What you probably mean is, "What types of objects are found in an object relational mapping of a database?"  In which case you would most likely find POCO classes.  (Plain Old Class Objects)

Comment: Maybe you can rephrase your question. From what I understand about relational DB a possible answer can be tables, views, SP, Functions, Triggers, PK, Indexes, etc